# How to get blob url quickly for video?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video, blob

I'm trying to generate a blob url similar to youtube blob urls, the code below is working perfectly, but there is a delay of at least 16 seconds to generate a 1 hour blob url for .mp4. Is there any way to generate a blob url that loads faster, similar to youtube, where their blob url is generated quickly. I'm starting now in blob so I'm a little lost. Thanks

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onloadend = function () {
  console.log('Start Player');
  var blob = new Blob([xhr.response]);
  var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.getElementById("video").src = blobUrl;
};

xhr.onloadstart = function () {
  console.log('Start loading');
};

xhr.open("GET", "/video.mp4", 1);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Are you sure your internet is not taking 16 seconds to download the 1 hour long video? Also It's possible that Youtube uses small chunks of the full video at a time. For example your `60 mins / 16 seconds` is around 4:15 mins of video time per second, maybe have the first chunk provide 4 mins of watching time, while the other chunks are downloaded during next 15 seconds?

Comment: PS: Why are you using a blob? I wonder if MSE is a better option for you, but it depends on what value this using blobs method is providing to your project...

Comment: @VC.One I'm getting error using MSE, it keeps giving incompatibility error in codecs

Comment: Ok. MSE expects **fragmented-MP4** format (not standard MP4). It's complicated why there is a difference (no time to lecture about MP4 bytes structure and why it's not suitable to "stream" and is only good for "progressive" downloading)... I still don't know why blobs are being used (_eg: "I'm trying to hide video URL"_ because then PHP would be better solution)...

Comment: To stream in chunks you have to first prepare your video clip... **To play chunks without MSE**, you could export (from some video editor) your video as segments (time ranges) of separate MP4 files then play each MP4 like a playlist using blobs (`1.mp4`, `2.mp4`, `3.mp3` etc). **Solution:** Where the full video needs 16 seconds, you instead have 16 pieces (chunks) that need 1 second to load. Each piece is a separate MP4 file that can be playable by itself. In JS you will an Array of length 16 where each slot holds an ArrayBuffer of one these loaded chunks.

Comment: The only problem with above method is each chunk must be "loaded" in to the player so each segment will start with browser showing a "busy" mode in the video tag (like a spinning circle to signify some loading process). This will break the flow of watching the video. So to use MSE you need a way to export fragmented MP4 (eg: using FFmpeg or maybe Handbrake if you prefer a clickable GUI over typing commands into FFmpeg). At this point it would be enough to just export your video as one fragmented MP4 because each frame has own header and it can begin playback without waiting for full 16 secs...

Comment: Okay, but when you refer to shredding this mp4 you say I convert to webm?

Comment: WebM is easier (works in MSE as it is) but also test if your video page will still work on iOS devices. As for converting to fragmented, then research if [MP4Box.js](https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/) can help you. I don't use (I use FFmpeg) but MP4Box claims to do on-the-fly fragmentation of a standard MP4... PS: They have a tool to check the MP4's codec values (to avoid the _"it keeps giving incompatibility error in codecs"_).

Comment: worked perfectly, but I have a doubt, does the MSE wait for the entire file to be loaded until it produces the video?

Comment: **(1)** What worked... using WebM? or using fragmented MP4? **(2)** No, it can play as the data downloads. Are you getting a problem like that and with what format?